# How to validate schema with Hibernate (all errors)

Tags: hibernate, validation

I am using Hibernate 3.2.6 with hbm files. When using option hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate, I receive only the first validation error. Is there a way to show all erros in schema?

Example:
City.hbm.xml file has a property called 'name'. When I drop that column from table, I get:
Missing column: name in nfe.dbo.city
So far OK. But, City.hbm.xml file has another property called state. When I drop 'state' column from table, I receieve the same error (Missing column: name in nfe.dbo.city) and would like to receive all erros in schema (not just the first one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get it to show all errors in the schema because of how the code is written. If you read the code for [Configuration.validateSchema()](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java.html) you'll see it throws a HibernateException on the first error found and thus ends the validation process.

Comment: thanks, well I might just change that code or implement my own validation process.

Answer (score 3):

I just created a custom Configuration class to get all the schema violations together. Posting the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jelies/8951881), could be useful to someone else :)

Comment: It would be awesome to add this to the hibernate maven plugin...  I may try to tackle that when I get some time.  I'll update if I do it.